# jQuery Expander plugin with angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

**HTML** (Angular binding)

```
 <p id="eventDescription">{{MyEvent.Item.Description}}</p>
```

**JS** (this code snippet also inside the above HTML file)

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('#eventDescription').expander();
    });

</script>
```

I do have an Angular Controller file also.

**Question :** I'm trying to use [jQuery Expander Plugin](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/index.html) to show "read more.." when there is more content on it.My problem is, it's not working with the angular binding text as shown above.But if I put a static text then it's Woking properly.So How can I use this plugin with angualrjs ?